# simple subclassing of UIButton in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, subclass

I think I've followed sample code to the letter, but the below is giving me an error.

I want to subclass UIButton and add a couple of properties, but I'm failing from the get-go.

I have created a subclass file. these are my .h/.m's:

```
// damButton.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface damButton : UIButton
{
    CGFloat _position;
}
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat position;
@end
```

and

```
// damButton.m
#import "damButton.h"

@implementation damButton

@synthesize position = _position;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

in my mainviewcontroller, I have imported my custom button, but when I use the property's inbuilt getter and setter, I get an error:

```
//MainViewController.m
#import "damButton.h"

// then within a method...
damButton *b = [damButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[b position:5.0];
```

generates this error: `No visible @interface for 'damButton' declares the selector 'position:'`

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, I've pretty much copied it verbatim (I think). I only want to use the inbuilt getters/setters (for now).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling the getter method, instead of the setter method -setPosition, i.e. try:

```
[b setPosition:5.0];
```

or

```
b.position = 5.0;
```

May I ask what you're trying to achieve by subclassing UIButton?

Comment: </banging head against desk> It must be late, I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. Should I just delete the question? To answer yours (and it's not easy to do it succinctly), I'm creating a little learning game with a dozen or more dynamically created buttons. I was using the tag and title properties to track it, but I need much more tracking. Adding a couple of properties will do it for me. I was using another NSMutableArray which I had to update along with the buttons, and I thought this might be a little easier.

Comment: @Madivad The question and answer could be of use to someone so don't delete it. I think for your use case it's fine to subclass UIButton. However, be aware of `+buttonWithType:` : `This method is a convenience constructor for creating button objects with specific configurations. It you subclass UIButton, this method does not return an instance of your subclass. If you want to create an instance of a specific subclass, you must alloc/init the button directly.` from [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Comment: ok, thanks for that. I am new to all this, and subclassing (although sounding simple in my head) appears to be much harder when I put it into practise :)